# My Magento store Warnings and Error messages for users are displaying on wrong pages

Tags: magento

Good Day I've got a magento store that is working perfectly fine. But the only issue is that Error messages are not displaying where they suppose to be displayed. 
[image]

For example the message displayed on the screenshot was supposed to be displayed on the onestepcheckout. But instead it is displayed on the homepage.

Comment: how do you get IE on ubuntu?

Comment: I used "payonlinux" to install IE this link will help you on how to install ie and other browsers on ubuntu https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PlayOnLinux

Answer (score 6, accepted):

hi @mthetheleli beseti

go to onestepcheckout controller and add this in indexAction near

```
  $this->loadLayout()
       ->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session')
       ->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session')
  $this->renderLayout();
```

add only $this->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session');

between   $this->loadLayout() and $this->renderLayout();

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Error messages are stored in sessions, so

If you have modified the redirects, removed the message blocks from templates or are using `->getGroupedHtml()` in enterprise instead of `->toHtml()` you will find these issues.

Once the message gets called it is cleared.

There are many different type of sessions models, but to me this to me looks like it is using either `core/session` or `checkout/session`